# Limiting Date (Hours) In Form

Tags: datetime

How can i limit Hours in Date field ? like it begins in 12 untill 21:00 .
Any idea would be appreciate it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'date restrictions' module might be what you need https://www.drupal.org/project/date_restrictions

Comment: thx i've used that but it's not working

Comment: What happens ? Have you checked the log .  Remember to clear the cache and check permissions!

Comment: this module create a section in date field , but it's empty

Comment: Is there any config?  After that if it where me I'd use a debugger (xdebug) to stick a breakpoint in and check why that section in the date field is empty and what data it needs.

Comment: you know, that was my mistake,i should enable 3 module comes whit date restriction .
but this module only can edit day,i wanna let user to select hours between 3 till 9

Comment: can the code be extended. As you're still dealing with the date field.    Otherwise would it be an option to deal with opening hours in a new field.  You could then use a dropdown for this selection.  And disabling hours in the date field.

Comment: thx for being great :)